# Adding Files to Apache Set Up (Mac OSX)

Tags: php, macos, apache

I have am trying to install OpenEMR and following the instructions here :

http://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/OpenEMR_3.1_OS_X_Macintosh_Installation

I am struggling with understanding what to do here:

When I run : `sudo vi /etc/apache2/other/openemr.conf`

I get a blank file.

It then goes on to add:

```
<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/openemr/documents>

order deny,allow

Deny from all

</Directory>

<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/openemr/openemr/edi>

order deny,allow

Deny from all

</Directory>

<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/openemr/era>

order deny,allow

Deny from all

</Directory>

ZZ
```

Can someone please shed light on what changes to the config files need to be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The openemr.conf file will be blank at first as you are creating the file. This config file sets up the required security settings for OpenEMR at the webserver level.

You'll want to add the following to your newly created openemr.conf file:

```
<Directory /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/openemr/sites/default/documents>
order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/openemr/sites/default/edi>
order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/openemr/sites/default/era>
order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

You'll want to place the openemr source files in `/Library?Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/openemr`

Are you installing for demonstration purposes, production use, or just to learn more about OpenEMR? There is also a [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/openemr/openemr/) version which may be useful - you could forego all the server level setup. Just pull the image down and start it up. All the Apache configuration is done for you.